# Using `$@.o` in Makefile dependency won't work

Tags: gnu-make

Trying a Makefile rule like the following did not work (GNU Make 4.0):

```makefile
foo:   $@.o other.o

bar:   bar.o other.o
```

The file `foo.c` was compiled (to `foo.o`), but the link command was `cc -o .o`.

In contrast, `bar` was compiled and linked correctly as `cc bar.o other.o -o bar`.

Who can explain the difference (or the problem)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is addressed in the section on [Automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) in the GNU Make manual:

> It’s very important that you recognize the limited scope in which automatic variable values are available: they only have values within the recipe. In particular, you cannot use them anywhere within the target list of a rule; they have no value there and will expand to the empty string. Also, they cannot be accessed directly within the prerequisite list of a rule. A common mistake is attempting to use `$@` within the prerequisites list; this will not work.

The rest of the paragraph gives one possible solution, albeit a GNU Make-specific one: [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html). Writing your Makefile as

```make
.SECONDEXPANSION:

foo:   $$@.o other.o

bar:   bar.o other.o
```

allows `$$@` to be given the appropriate value, and then

```
$ make foo
cc    -c -o foo.o foo.c
cc    -c -o other.o other.c
cc   foo.o other.o   -o foo
```

does what you’re hoping it to do.

(In my experience, there are usually better ways of addressing a problem than resorting to secondary expansion, but that can only be determined by understanding the overall goal of what you’re trying to do.)